# keyword search on title

Tags: javascript, node.js

The current code provides me with the data based on id of the API. My idea is to create a search based on keyword for it.

The idea is when you search for 'coding', it should log the data/posts with the keyword as a title.

```js
function script(id) {
  request(`https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/${id}.json`, function (error, res, body) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      let myData = (JSON.parse(body))
      var titleUrl = `https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=${myData.id}`;
      request(titleUrl, function (err, res, body) {
          console.log(myData.title);
          console.log(myData.score)
          console.log(titleUrl)
      });
    }
  });
}

script(23202120);
```

Answer (score 0):

The second request does not return `json` instead it returns a html-page. You can use a html-parser like https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio to actually read the contents of the page.

```
...
 request(titleUrl, function (err, res, body) {
          const $ = cheerio.load(body);
          const title = $('title');
          console.log(title);
          ...

      });
...
```